# How can I average these user inputs?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

The program does as intended, prompts a user to enter an age until the user enters "-1". Once the user enters this, the program is intended to tell you the largest, smallest, and AVERAGE. I got it all working fine except I'm unsure how to average the inputs, any help is appreciated!

UPDATE: Thanks to all who helped, I have updated the code. The only thing left is that I don't get the correct average. I have included the updated code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, large, small;
    int sumOfAges = 0;
    double averageAge = 0.0;
    int Num = 0;
    printf("Enter an age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    large = n;
    small = n;



    while(n != -1)
    {
        printf("Enter an age: \n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n>large)
        large = n;
        if(n < small && n != -1)
        small = n;
        sumOfAges += n;
        Num++;
    }

     averageAge = (sumOfAges/Num);

    printf("\n The largest age is %d", large);
    printf("\n The smallest age is %d", small);
    printf("\n The average age is %lf", averageAge);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how average is calculated?

Comment: @Eugene, yes. Add all, then divide by the amount of numbers. I'm new to coding and C so I apologize if your question was sarcastic. I just need some pointers on how to go about implementing this.

Comment: You already have the loop. You just need to have 2 more variables, one for the sum (add `n`), the second to count how many numbers (add +1). Then display result of calculation (not forgetting to cast to float or double, to avoid rounding down).

Comment: I wasn't sarcastic, just trying to direct you instead of giving away the answer. So what do you need to calculate the average? The total sum and the number of elements. Do you know how to calculate each one of these?

Comment: No, the question was sincere. Clearly, you need a counter for the number of entries and a variable to accumulate them, just as your textual explanation states.

Comment: @jh365: you do not need *pointers* to do this, define 2 local variables, initialize tem to 0, add each age to one as it is entered and increment the other by one, print the division of the first by the second, unless no numbers have been entered, in which case nothing should be printed. You currently do not support for the first input to be `-1`, nor do you check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: @chqrlie "Pointers" as in help, not pointers in a C sense :D

Comment: @AntonH: hence the use of italics ;-)

Comment: Note that you will treat -1 as a valid value in the body of the loop (and it'll probably be the smallest value, unless the user enters -2 or some other negative value first.  As so often, the difficulty is in validating the user's input.  You should also test the result of `scanf()` — if the user types `age 10`, your program will run a long time (because the `a` isn't a digit, so it leaves it to be read by the next input operation, which finds it isn't a digit, so …).  You'll need to do some modest modifications to avoid such problems.

Comment: Best to rollback your code to what it was.  The SO model here is you post, people answer.  Not an iterative session of updating code.

Comment: @chux sorry man didn't know what else to do because I can't comment code. Won't happen again boss

Comment: @jh365  The updated version of the program is invalid. The first entered value can be -1. In this case the program will output an invalid result. See my answer. There is shown how the program can be written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the average you should accumulate all ages and divide them by the number of the entered ages.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int largest, smallest;
    int n, total;

    n = 0;
    total = 0;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        int age;

        printf( "Enter an age (-1 - exit) : " );

        if ( scanf( "%d", &age ) != 1 || age == -1 ) break;

        if ( n++ == 0 )
        {
                largest = smallest = age;
        }
        else if ( largest < age )
        {
                largest = age;
        }
        else if ( age < smallest )
        {
                smallest = age;
        }

        total += age;
    }

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        printf( "\nThe largest age is %d", largest );
        printf( "\nThe smallest age is %d", smallest );
        printf( "\nThe average age is %d\n", total / n );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter an age (-1 - exit) : 10
Enter an age (-1 - exit) : 20 
Enter an age (-1 - exit) : 15 
Enter an age (-1 - exit) : 16 
Enter an age (-1 - exit) : 25
Enter an age (-1 - exit) : 21
Enter an age (-1 - exit) : -1

The largest age is 25
The smallest age is 10
The average age is 17
```

I do not think that outputting the average age as a double value is a good idea in this case. However if you want you can declare the variable `total` as having type double.:)

Answer (score 2):

Inside your while statement you should keeping track of the number of inputs, and the total value of the inputs

```
 int numberOfInputs = 0;
 int totalValue = 0;

 while(n != -1)
 {
     numberOfInputs++;
     totalValue += n;
     // Your other While-loop code here
 }
```

The average in than found by dividing the totalValue by the numberOfInputs.

```
float Average = (float)totalValue/numberOfInputs;
```

Note I cast this to a float so the calculation is done in floating point, not integer, arithmetic.

Comment: Do you mean 'total/numberOfInput?'

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but you have an infinite loop... and your average formula is incorrect (which is not obvious at first sight ;-)

Comment: 1) Don't ask about votes in the answer body. It is unrelated. 2) Yes, downvote has to be explained, otherwise it's useless. 3) I can think of several reasons for this DV (not mine): a) Giving away a trivial answer instead of teaching the OP something. b) Usage of (potentially) uninitialized variables. c) As stated - infinite loop as written

Comment: @EugeneSh, sorry had to ask in the body, I didn't have the rep to comment. Now I do.

Answer (score 2):

To find the average in this case, you need to determine the value of N, that is, the number of age-values of which you wish to find the average (as a floating point value) within your while loop, and add each new age (as integer values)to the total age value, storing both N, and the sum of ages along with `smallest` and `largest`.

```
//...your vars
int sumOfAges = 0;
double averageAge = 0.0;
int N = 0;

while(age != -1)
{
  printf("Enter an age: \n");
  scanf("%d",&age);
    if (age != -1){
        if (age>max)
           max = age;
        if(age < min)
           min = age;

        sumOfAges += age;
        N++;
    }
}
```

Then, compute the average as `averageAge = ((double)sumOfAges/N);`

Comment: Don't use `N` and `n` as variable names.  Use meaningful names.

Comment: 'N' is commonly used in statistics, and is meaningful for this reason.  Why deny the history of the field in its application?

Comment: Identifiers that differ only in _case_ tend to be harder to understand/differentiate  than identifiers that differ in text.  Using `age` vs. `n` would help separate `n` from `N`.

Comment: @chux, duly noted.  Thanks.

Comment: So far, this has worked. Except that the result does not give the expected average. I will update the original post with the new code. Thanks so much for the help

Comment: @chux, noted sorry